# How to retrieve last fragment after activity recreated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an **Activity** which has a  fragment. Inside the **Fragment** I am creating **Camera Intent**.
Since **Camera** is another activity, my main activity might be destroyed when user is taking picture.

After user finishes taking picture I want my activity come back to latest **Fragment**. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` but it didn't work. Since activity is being destroyed it didn't have any transaction info.

Thanks

Comment: did you get solution ??

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to solve this issue. What I would do is store the latest fragment in a SingleTon class instance or in SharedPreferences and in onResume activity you can check the last fragment and attach it back your FragmentActivity.

The other solution would be to start your CameraActivity by expecting a result, e.g startActivityForResult. in that way your Fragment Activity will remain in the stack and whenever you are done with your CameraActivity, you will be returned back to onActivityResult of your MainActivity.

If you can share your code here, we can be more helpful.

Comment: That's what I am  doing actually. I am starting activity for result. I am about to solve it, backstack was null because of another reason I guess, now it has data. I can pop latest fragment I guess. Thank you tho!

Comment: Ok then, let me know if it doesn't work. we can find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps FragmentManager could work for you, launch the camera as a fragment and add the main fragment to the backstack.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html

Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Camera is an activity not fragment. Secondly, I already mentioned on top, since Main Activity is being destroyed, backstack will be `null`

Answer (score 0):

*For retrieving the past `Fragment`, add that `Fragment` to the back stack  so that when the camera `Activity` is closed it will be again pushed to the front.


  For example paste the following code in your `Fragment`

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("null").commit();*